# Aspose.PDF integration with Microsoft 365 and Sharepoint

Tags: office365, sharepoint-2013, aspose, aspose.pdf

I have the requirements of viewing/editing the PDF documents in-line / from with-in the browser for my ASP.NET/C# web application for which we are considering Aspose.PDF. Does Microsoft 365 and share-point integration with Aspose is available. Microsoft and Aspose product team can update here? 
Also does Aspose support integration with Sharepoint for storing the documents or Azure blob store please confirm.

Comment: Aspose.PDF for SharePoint can be used with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation and Microsoft SharePoint Server. You may visit [documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfsharepoint/Home) for detailed information including the installation. Please further elaborate your concerns about Office 365 integration and Azure blob storage.

**PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Please note I don't have sharepoint 365 in current stack. We also have the requirment of viewing / editing the PDF document from web app what is Aspose recommendation in this regards.

Comment: You may take a look at [HTML5 PDF Editor](https://github.com/aspose-pdf/Aspose.PDF-for-.NET/blob/master/Showcases/HTML5_PDF_Editor_by_Aspose_Pdf_NET/README.md) which is a showcase demonstrating the implementation of API features in your applications.